# How to prove EVERY sequence converges to L in limit of function?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, proof-explanation, sequence-of-function

**Statement:**
Let $f: D \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and let $c$ be an accumulation point of D. Then $\lim_{x \rightarrow c} f(x) = L$ iff **for every sequence** $(s_n)$ in $D$ that converges to $c$ with $s_n \ne c$ for all $n$, the sequnece $(f(s_n))$ converges to $L$.

**Proof:**
Suppose $\lim_{x \rightarrow c} f(x) = L$. **Let $(s_n)$ be a sequence** in $D$ that converges to $c$ with $s_n \ne c$ for all $n$.  We must show that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} f(s_n)=L$.
Since $s_n \rightarrow c$, there exists $N$ such that $n > N \Rightarrow  |s_n - c| < \delta$ . Thus, for $n>N$ we have $0<|s_n - c| < \delta$, so that $|f(s_n) - L| < \epsilon$.  Hence $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f(s_n)=L$.

**My question:**  The statement says if every sequence $(s_n)$ converge to $c$, but the proof gave one sequence $(s_n)$. Does one case imply all? Don't I have to find all converging sequences in the space of $D$ first?

Comment: The chosen sequence is arbitrary, so the proof works for every sequence.

Comment: I guess I don't have to prove for all sequence in D. I just need to worry about the one I pick?

Comment: This is the classical way to prove that something is true **for every** "objects" : the sequence you picked can be every sequence. So what you said about it works the same for every sequence, so it is true for every sequence.

Comment: How can the sequence I pick be every sequence? I picked just one sequence.

Comment: Ok : can you prove the following statement : "for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, there exists $y \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $x < y$". Can you try to write a rigourous proof for this statement ?

Comment: Similar to: "for all $\epsilon > 0 $, there exists a $\delta > 0$", so, $\epsilon$ depends on $\delta$. That means, x depends on the y we picked?

Comment: Can you write the proof rigorously ? How will your proof begin ?

Comment: I'm not sure how to prove it, because it's impossible for me to list all the x in $\mathbb{R}$. Care to give a lead?

Comment: Ok. A correct way to write the proof is the following : "Let $x$ be a real number. Define $y=x+1$. Obviously, $x<y$, so there exists $y \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $x<y$". The point is that to prove that something is true for every real number, you just have to pick one "random" number, and to prove the statement for this one. Here, the $x$ I picked can be $2$, or $4.5$ or $-\pi$ or all the numbers ! So the proof works for every number, because the one I chose is general, it represents all the numbers that can be chosen... Is that clear ?

Comment: @TheSilverDoe I think a reasonable response to that could be "But what if I find a number for which that doesn't work?", because for example, you may not have convinced some sceptics that $x + 1$ is always greater than $x$, or that $x+1$ always exists for any real $x$. But then pointing a sceptic like this towards Rudin's PMA Chapter 1, where rigorous definitions of fields and real numbers are, usually suffices.

Comment: Basically what @TheSilverDoe is saying is, that the whole reasoning in the proof isn’t relying on anything specific to the sequence $S(n)$, therefore one can be sure that it holds for all sequences

Comment: When I see "random." I think of probability and statistics. Example: "x is a random number from normal distribution." Say, I oberserved x=5 from normal dist., can I infer anything about the distribution. Probably not. Not sure if I make any sense in explaining my confusion.

Comment: That's why I put some "..." around the word random. I just want to say that proving something for one *general* number (as @GrigoriPerelman said, not using anything specific to this number), is enough to prove it for all numbers.

Comment: If I understand correctly, we didn't really prove that $x$ will work for all reals. We just assume it's true (and the if part is done), then proceeded to the rest of the proof (the then part).

Comment: @user13985 yeah we did prove that $x$ will work  for all reals because $x<x+1$ is a direct consequence of the addition and order axioms. check my answer, same thought process extends to this example as well. (maybe it is misleading to call it some random x, we can just say it is the same x we used when creating axioms etc..)

Comment: But we only CLAIMED it works for all reals. We didn't PROVE it works for all reals. I guess like we discussed, it is assumed that when we say "let x be a real number", this x is a representative of all reals.

Comment: @user13985 what would you consider as a proof then? Some way to check the claim for all real numbers?

Comment: @GrigoriPerelman After reading the statement over and over, I think my interpretation of it was wrong. When it says "for every sequence in D...", it's more like saying: "if a sequence in D is..." Just like what @ AdamRubinson pointed out below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When stating the definitions, theorems, properties etc. about (ALL)sequences, we are using "$a_n$","$x_n$","$a_k$",..."$s_n$" as a general sequence to make the statement. I am telling you here that the $s_n$ sequence in the proof you gave, is actually that "$a_n$"...("$s_n$") general sequence for which statements were made earlier when the sequences were initially defined and figured out. So if you prove something for $s_n$ it means you have actually proved something for sequences in general. And you may ask how do you know that is the exact same sequence, well you can compare it with those "$\text{general}$" sequences, and see if there is anything different about it. (There isn't anything different, that is why we were saying in the comments that there is nothing specific about it, and that it is actually a general sequence).

But basically when it is said "Let $s_n$ be a sequence", it is actually meant "Let $s_n$ be the same general sequence we made statements about before"(unless stated otherwise), so if we discover something new(make a conclusion) about that general sequence, that new statement actually extends to all sequences in the same way the definitions and properties of "original general sequences" were extending to all sequences.

Hope this clarifies

Comment: I don't get the notation of sequences with quotations around them. Are you saying $a_n, x_n, a_k, s_n \in \mathbb{R}$ ? Loosely speaking, $s_n$ is like a representative of all sequences that satisfy the condition. In this case, the condition is all numbers in the real.

Comment: @user13985 the notation of sequences with quotations around them are just the common examples of how the sequences are usually denoted in mathematical statements about them. I also wanted to make it obvious that, it could as well $s_n$ be used for some of the most fundamental sequence statements, which would make it more clear why proving it for $s_n$ proves it for all sequences. Yeah, $s_n$ is like a representative, I wanted to phrase it like that myself. I don't quite get the part where you say that 'the condition is all numbers in the real'. Feel free to clarify

Comment: This is part I didn't understand: [the $s_n$ sequence in the proof you gave, is actually that "$a_n$"...("$s_n$") general sequence.] Is it missing "is the" in front "general sequence"?

Comment: @user13985 "the $s_n$ sequence in the proof you gave, is actually that general sequence for which statements were made earlier when the sequences were initially defined and figured out." Does this make more sense ? I just dropped the part in quotations, since it apparently looks confusing

Comment: Yes, this makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Another way to word the conclusion of your proof is:

Suppose $\lim_{x \rightarrow c} f(x) = L$. Then:

**If** $(s_n)$ is a sequence in $D$ that converges to $c$ with $s_n \ne c$ for all $n$, **then** $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f(s_n)=L$.

More importantly though, your proof only proves one way ($ \Rightarrow $) and hasn't attempted to prove the converse statement ($\Leftarrow $) it said it was going to.

Comment: I guess this isn't clear? Fair.

Comment: I thought it's good, don't know who downvoted! Giving a +1.

Comment: Honestly, I think my answer is not that clear if you're sceptically-minded.

Comment: I don't see how "for every sequence" and "if $(s_n)$ is a sequence" are equivalent.

Comment: Those two phrases are not equivalent. However, "Statement A implies Statement B" is the same as, "if statement A is true then statement B must be true" which is the same as, "Let Statement A be true. Then Statement B is true", which is the same as, "whenever Statement A is true, Statement B is true", which is the same as, "Consider an *arbitrarily* chosen instance of Statement A being true. Then Statement B is true", which is the same as, "each/every instance of Statement A being true will never give rise to Statement B being False: it will always give rise to Statement B being true".

Comment: At least, that's the conventional wisdom, and most of mathematics is build upon it. If you want to debate it I think you're entering more into the realm of philosophy than mathematics.